# NSLayoutConstraint format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

The First image is use else if, 
after I change if, when compile is not have any issue until I click other page then have a error, the error is

```
NSInvalidArgumentExeception, reas: 'Unable to prase constraint format: @"V:[allCssLabel]-0-[individualLabel]"
```

I try to change `@"V:|-[allCssLabel]-0-[individualLabel]-|"`, still have a error, I want to know how to fix the problem
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the first constraint, you have "allCssLabel" in format, but "allDirectBusinessLabel" in dictionary

Comment: I would suggest to use EasyPeasy  library that dramatically decrease your delelop time for constraints

Comment: https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy

Comment: still having the issue?

Comment: The issue is fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in "format" should correspond views in variable bindings dictionary.
[image: You have incorrect name in variable bindings]